# Facebook API: redirect_uri

Tags: php, facebook, .htaccess, facebook-graph-api, oauth

I've readeded that FB API have problems with redirect_uri - and i've try to make it work on my framework. Problem is easy, but i haven't found working solution so i think this is right place, and someone help me.

I've creating login link:

```
$loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl( $app_url . 'fb/oauth/' , $permissions );
```

where $app_url . 'fb/oauth/' looks like this http://domain.com/fb/oauth/

This path is redirected thru htaccess > index.php (routing) > plugins/facebook/facebook-callback.php

And in oauth.php file i've valid code - but i've get error:

> Error validating verification code. Please make sure your redirect_uri is identical to the one you used in the OAuth dialog request

Main problem is that i don't want to redirect to domain.com/fb_oauth.php - i prefer to use rewrite/route way to be more pretty. Everything is correct, i've checked slash at the end (because some have problems with that).

I also think that error may be in the way that route redirect to callback file:

```
if($route->path = 'fb/oauth') {
    include $app_path . "plugins/Facebook/facebook-callback.php";
} else {
    die("Unknown");
}
```

Please help me - i don't have other ideas. I prefer to not use direct link to .php, and use my way (my variables are defined before include destination file)

Thank You !

EDIT:
I've also try domain.com/oauth and domain.com/oauth/
same error :-(

Comment: Which helper is that you are using there, the RedirectLoginHelper? In that case, did you follow the code examples at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/howto/example_facebook_login ?

Comment: Yes i'm using getRedirectLoginHelper. I'm using those code examples.

Comment: I think if you do not explicitly specify the redirect URI, then it automatically takes the current URL. You could try calling `getLoginUrl` again with the same parameter in the second script that processes the code (not sure if that's going to work though, it might cause a problem with the CSRF protection.)

Comment: As You say... not working. I'm almost sure that i can't do it my way, because of routing. File that parsing index.php is as file receiver. I made this for now using standalone file oauth.php. Maybe the best way is to use some other frameworks packages that work on routing paths.

Comment: Internal routing doesn't matter, just the URLs seen "from the outside."

Comment: Maybe Facebook api has a bug - it works only when redirecting directly to file .php :-(